# Magento 2.4.1 PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 2147483648 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 176128 bytes)

Tags: magento2.4.1

This error(Allowed memory size of 2147483648 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in vendor/magento/framework/Serialize/Serializer/Json.php on line 37) is populated when we access the category page (this category is top level category which shows all products (we have only 20-24 configurable products)). Not each time but it come after 10-12 days interval on the production environment.

We recently upgraded our server memory from  4g to 8g to solve this issue but it is still there.

We use nginx and php-fpm

We also updated the memory limit from .user.ini file from both the location m2 root and Pub

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am also having the same issue, could you plz suggest how you solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

As per the error report, you set memory_limit 2G (2147483648 bytes). Increase to 3G or 4G maybe fix the issue. Make sure memory_limit is updated properly using phpinfo().

[image]

Local value is the final memory limit value.

Also, we can add `ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');` in PHP, telling the server to just use all the memory that it wants.

Changing the memory_limit by `ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');` is not a proper solution. Try using Xdebug to profile your script and find out where all that memory went and fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

we have the error for
...StoreRepository.php on line 112

But what ever limit is set as local and global value (6G), the error returns

Seems to be something else...